# What's the malloc checksum logic in iOS?

Tags: ios, crash, malloc, checksum

What's the reasoning of the checksum.  How and when is it checked (e.g. before/after allocation, before/after deallocation)?

Why am I interested?  Read on.

While porting a large project to arm64, I'm running into some tough to diagnose crashes having to with that ever so popular malloc checksum failure.  I've set watchpoints on the offending address and it's always the same offset from the base address.  This address is a member variable of a CPP class (and it's just a 32 bit integer).  The project has some C and CPP mixed together with ObjC, which makes me lean towards alignment bugs.

The watchpoints seldom ever hit, only at the beginning of the use of the object, then they're left alone, yet still it crashes at this same address.

I understand it's intended to identify writing to invalid address, but knowing how/when it's performed could help shed some light on this bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checksums in `malloc` functions are generally performed for the *control* information held for a block (not the data area), for example the sixteen bytes immediately preceding the address you're given, which holds information such as block size, next block, checksum and so on.

And the most logical time for setting it is upon block allocation (or reallocation if it's done in-place) since the information tends not to change otherwise.

It's also generally *checked* at deallocation time, to catch the situation where an errant write has corrupted the control information.

I would suggest that, if you're writing to a *positive* offset from the allocated memory (your "member varaible of a CPP class") and that's causing the issue, then you haven't allocated enough memory for it. In other words, you're writing over the control information for the *next* block (free or allocated, probably doesn't matter to the checking code).

Keep in mind that's based on general knowledge of how memory arenas work, not *specific* details of the iOS one. But there's a fair amount of commonality in all I've seen. It makes sense to set the checksum on `malloc/realloc` and check it on `free`, as much sense as it makes to not bother checking it at any other time.

And, based on the operation you state is corrupting, it's likely it's a buffer overrun rather than underrun.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.  Direct hit!  Regarding the control data, would this usually be for a whole block of memory or in the case of CPP, the range of each heap instantiated object?  To my knowledge, CPP member vars are stored together like a struct (e.g. no preceding 16 bytes for control info, unless it was at the beginning of the object itself, like when new is used instead of malloc).  I'm not specifically writing to that address either, only in the first method call to initialize.  But it would make sense if something else was uncontrollably writing into that preamble range.

Comment: @Joey, the control info is a malloc thing, you'd end up with `|control|your-data|` (for each `malloc` done) where `&your-data` is the address you get back from `malloc`. In other words, provided you write only in the `|your-data|` areas, you shouldn't corrupt the memory arena.

Comment: Thanks @paxdiablo.  So since the object is allocated via a call to new, it will result in a malloc for sizeof(ClassName) bytes with a region of control data preceding those bytes, which returns the pointer to the first byte of my data.  In the case that a heap object were allocated shortly before it (potentially not far behind the control region address space) and was overflown, it could corrupt the control region of that object, causing the checksum failure after the deallocation.  Is that a logical assumption?

Comment: It's _one_ possibility. `new` is not actually required to use the same arena as `malloc` but it often does. But I don't think the `new/malloc` distinction even matters here. If they're using the same arena, any object (C/CPP) can corrupt the control area of another (C/CPP). Bottom line, I think there's an overflow somewhere, it may require some serious looking at the code to find the possibilities and then fix those. Heap overflows are often the hardest bugs to track down.

Comment: Well I'm much closer now with this information.  Many thanks for the insight.